# python upload image and save it at database sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, image, better-sqlite3

#I want to allow the user to upload a picture and save it in the database(sqlite3), I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
def filedialogs(self):
    global get_img
    get_img = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("png","*.png"),("jpg","*.jpg"),("Allfile","*.*")))

def convert_image_into_binary(self,filename):
    with open(filname, 'rd') as file:
        photo_image=file.read()
    return photo_image

def Add_car(self):
    self.con = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
    self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()
    self.insert_photo = self.convert_image_into_binary(photo)
    sqlite_insert_blob_query = '''INSERT INTO cars_info(carmake, carmodel, caryear, cartransmition, carfuel, carcolor, carengine, carpreviousowners, carorigin, carmileage, carnumofpassengers, carlincesplatenum, carimageone) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'''
    entities = (self.makecb.get(), self.modelcb.get(), self.Yearcb.get(), self.Transmissioncb.get(),self.Fuelcb.get(), self.colorcb.get(), self.Enginedisplacementcb.get(), self.PreviousownersE.get(),self.Vehicleorigincb.get(), self.mileagecb.get(), self.numofpasscb.get(), self.lincesplatenum.get(),self.insert_photo)
                
    self.cursorObj.execute(sqlite_insert_blob_query, entities)

    self.con.commit()
    print("image and file inserted successfully as a blob into a table")
    self.cursorObj.close()
```

#So, Can anyone help me, I am stuck at this?

Comment: i got this error:

Answer (score 0):

with open(**filname**, 'r**d**') as file:

should read

with open(**filename**, 'r**b**') as file:

Also, when you call `self.convert_image_into_binary(photo)`, *photo* hasn't been defined.

Comment: thank you for your answer, is there any way to define (photo) so it can solve the problem?

Comment: It needs to be set to the filename of the image you're converting somewhere, like photo = 'photo.jpg'

Comment: yes for sure, but my goal is to let the user upload photos by himself you can see the def filedialogs(self)

Comment: Then photo should be get_img, assuming you call filedialogs somewhere.

Are these methods part of a class?

Comment: dave, I appreciate your cooperation
thank you for your response, I am trying to create functions that allow the user to upload a picture and then save it in the sqlite3 database, so first in the def filedialogs function: the user will load an image, and in def convert_image_into_binary: it will convert the image to blob so I can add it in the database, but there is a problem with my method, so is there another method that will help me achieve this. and yes its part of a class, thanks in advance